# Compare string to float in Python

Tags: string, floating-point, python-2.x

I tried this in python shell

```
>>> a='apple'
>>> b=11.1
>>> a>b
True
>>> a
'apple'
>>> b>a
False
```

Can someone explain to me how `a>b` is True? When `a` is an string and `b` is float.

Comment: Would you rather have an `'apple'` or an `11.1`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int/3270689#3270689

Comment: You can find more info here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int

Comment: @jramirez I don't know if you have enough rep points but the most helpful thing is to flag this as a duplicate.

Comment: @Joe then why didn't you flag it ? not trying to be snarky.

Comment: I was the first to flag it. Look ^.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Order comparison between elements of different types was a "design bug" in Python 2.x that has been removed in Python 3 (where you get a runtime error).

Correcting it wasn't an option before 3.x because of a lot of existing software that does sorting on heterogeneous containers (and version 3 is the first in which backward compatibility is intentionally broken).

In Python 2.x you can compare anything for `<`/`>`, with the only exception of complex numbers where this is explicitly forbidden.

The ordering result of comparison of different types is arbitrary but fixed at least for a given run of the Python interpreter, see http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in .  Values of different non-numeric types are always considered different.

Comment: Putting it in simple terms It is bug in 2.x, gives quite random results and removed from 3.x

Comment: @GauravAgarwal: "random" is excessive, it's arbitrary (e.g. if `'a'<3`   then any string is less than any integer) and you can for example implement a sorting because you get transitivity. It was a design bug that could not be fixed before python 3.x because people started depending on it.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, comparison between incomparable types often "works", giving meaningless results. Sometimes it's fun: `'aleph0' > float('+inf')`. But most of the time it's just silly.

So [Python 3 has removed this](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons), and `'a' > 1.0` quite reasonably raises a `TypeError` under it.