# What will be the output of this Python 2.x program?

Tags: python

Here is the program:

```
score = raw_input("Enter your score between 0.0 and 1.0: ")
try:
    fscore = float(score)
except:
    print "Enter a numerical value for score."
    exit()
if fscore >= 0.0 and fscore <= 1.0:
    if fscore >= 0.9:
        print "A"
    elif fscore >= 0.8:
        print "B"
    elif fscore >= 0.7:
        print "C"
    elif fscore >= 0.6:
        print "D"
    elif score >= 0.5:
        print "E"
    elif score < 0.5:
        print "F"
else:
    print "Score is out of range."
```

This is a simple program to give grades to students based on their score. If you notice carefully, I have made a semantic error in the 4th `elif` statement. Instead of writing `elif fscore >= 0.5`, I have written `elif score >= 0.5`.

What's intriguing me is if I pass `0.4` in `score`, this program gives me output `E`. Shouldn't I receive an error? And even if I am not receiving an error, why `E`? Why not `A` or `B` or anything else?

Comment: I'm new to this community and to python. I didn't know what to search for.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has something to do with the answer provided in this thread:
[Compare string to float in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713498/compare-string-to-float-in-python)

Notice that you are actually comparing a string (the input of the user) to a float (the 0.5 set in your elif). Apparently it is a design bug.

Note: I did not know this up front either :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it has been market duplicate and I have got my answer. :)